# Is $\pi=\ln(-1)/\sqrt{-1}$, and if so what does this mean?

Tags: complex-analysis

Using the complex integral

$z=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$

$\frac{dz}{dx}=-\sin(x)+i\cos(x)$

$dz=i[\cos(x)+i\sin(x)]dx$

$dz=iz\cdot dx$

$\frac{1}{z}dz=i\cdot dx$

$\ln(z)=ix$

$z=e^{ix}$

$\cos(x)+i\sin(x)=e^{ix}$

$x=\pi$

$\cos(\pi)-i\sin(\pi)=e^{i\pi}$

$-1=e^{i\pi}$

$\ln(-1)=i\pi$

$\frac{\ln(-1)}{i}=\pi$

$i=\sqrt{-1}$

$\pi=\frac{\ln(-1)}{\sqrt{-1}}$

A friend told me that a possible problem with this is that the log function is only defined for real numbers and this is a complex natural log. I'm wondering if it's a valid equality, and if so what does it mean/indicate?

Comment: Yes, it is a valid equality. Just search up Euler's identity.

Comment: There's a lot of symbol-pushing here. I'm afraid it doesn't hold up as a formal proof.

Comment: It's worth noting that the complex logarithm is multivalued - sure, $e^0=1$, but so does $e^{2i\pi}=1$ (and any integer multiple of $2i\pi$) - so it's not as simple as it is when restricted to the positive real numbers.

Comment: I can find the general form $e^{i*pi}=-1$, but not the form rewritten to isolate pi nor it's meaning.

Do you have any idea what it means that a transcendental number is equal to a ratio of two terms that have no real world context?

Comment: @AlecRhea It means exactly the same as the $e^{i\pi}=-1$ that you started with. It means that $\pi$ radians are required to rotate 1 on the Argand plane to the point -1, with respect to the origin.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall I don't know how to upvote on here but thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions, Yes this is perfectly valid, however, is missing a bit of the full picture in that square roots and the complex natural log are multi-valued. As for what it means or indicates, it seems better to ask what we want out of a generalization. We have a system where exponentiation and logarithms make sense for real numbers and we want to extend this concept to complex numbers in a way that still makes sense. Euler gave us one way to do this. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm